# Problems with stored procedures

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

```
create procedure SpecialPrice(IN T_ID int,Discount_P Decimal(5,3))
Begin

Update Ticket
set Price=Price*Discount_P
where T_ID = Ticket_ID ;

End@
```

I want to create a stored procedure that will update discounted price on the table ticket  however i am having trouble creating this stored procedure and it has error and since i am running these codes with IBM Data studio the displaye these errors beside Please Help

```
The errors : 

1)on the line Begin

DB2 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows: "Begin

Update Audience
set Price=Price*Discount_P
where T_ID = Ticket_ID" appears to be misplaced. 

2) On the line END@
     DB2 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows: Unexpected text "End@" encountered.
```

Answer (score 1):

set the Statement Terminator from `;` to `@` in Data Studio, under the Editor field
you find Validation. There you can Change the Statement Terminator.

Comment: or you can type --#SET TERMINATOR @